# How to connect to Postgresql from Ruby On Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am new in Ruby on rails and i am using ruby v 1.9.3 & rails 3.2.12 with window 7

i want to PostgreSQL database connection in my app.

this is my db connection

```
development:  
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mmagap_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: postgres
  password: root

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mmagap_test
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: root

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  encoding: unicode
  database: mmagap_production
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: root
```

**this connection every time give error**

```
D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in
`initialize': received invalid response to SSL negotiation: - (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

Please help how to create PostgreSQL database connection in my RoR app.

Comment: What environment is giving you that error? Are all of them giving you that error?

Comment: Did you check database is created ?

Answer (score 2):

First install pg gem

```
    gem install pg
```

your apps database.yml file shoud be like this

```
development:   
    adapter: postgresql  
    encoding: unicode  
    database: myapp_development  
    pool: 5  
    username: myapp  
    password: password1  

test:  
  adapter: postgresql  
  encoding: unicode  
  database: myapp_test  
  pool: 5  
  username: myapp  
  password: password1
```

Now run

```
rake db:setup    
rake db:migrate
```

and after this run

```
rails s
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change `host: 127.0.0.1` to `host: localhost`. It should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to verify, Is Postgresql installed successfully or not.

DigitalOceanCommunityArticle [Click Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-12-04)

AskUbuntuLink [Click Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287786/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 0):

Removed `host` from development config in `database.yml`,its worked for me.

```
development:  
      adapter: postgresql
      database: tes
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
      username: postgres
      password: root
```

Answer (score 0):

**First you should install PostgreSQL and PgAdmin**

After installing this thing you will have to add some pic of code ( to connect PostgreSQL to your rails project ) in your project config/database.yml file (before add PostgreSQL code you will have to remove all Sqlite3 code from config/database.yml file).

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: your_PostgreSQL_username
  password: your_PostgreSQL_password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  username: your_PostgreSQL_username
  password: your_PostgreSQL_password

staging:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

production:
 url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

postgres is default username and password in PostgreSQL database\

after add this pic of code you have to add one line of code in your rails project root directory in Gemfile

```
gem ‘pg’
```

and you must have to remove sqlite3 code from Gemfile ( gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4' )before adding gem 'pg'